# Fields not populated upon flushing to database Spring JPA

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, flush

I have two entities, `UploadEntity` and `UploadStoreEntity`. These map to tables *u_upload* and *us_upload_store*. Table *u_upload* contains a foreign key reference to *us_upload_store*, called *us_id*.

I recently added a `NOT NULL` constraint to the *us_id* column, so I'm trying to ensure this field is populated in `uploadEntity` in the code below, before flushing to the database. However, it is failing as it is **not** populated upon flushing, even though `uploadStoreEntity.getId()` returns a non-null value. Please could somebody help me understand why?

```
public IUpload putUpload(final IUpload upload, final byte[] contents, final String contentType) {
    final UploadEntity uploadEntity = this.mapperService.toEntity(upload);
    this.uploadDao.save(uploadEntity);

    final StoredUploadMetadata metadata = new StoredUploadMetadata();

    metadata.setValue("u.id", String.valueOf(uploadEntity.getId()));

    final IStoredUpload<?> storedUpload = this.UploadStoreManager.putUpload(contents, metadata);

    // ContentLength populated during call to putUpload()
    uploadEntity.setSize(storedUpload.getMetadata().getContentLength());

    final UploadStoreEntity uploadStoreEntity = this.uploadStoreDao.save(new UploadStoreEntity());

    uploadEntity.setUploadStoreId(uploadStoreEntity.getId());

    final UploadEntity updatedUploadEntity = this.uploadDao.saveAndFlush(uploadEntity);

    return this.mapperService.toDTO(updatedUploadEntity);
}
```

Stack trace:

```
2019-03-17 12:14:41,493 level=ERROR logger=com.petehallw.rest.advice.ValidationExceptionHandler | The request has produced an exception
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute batch; SQL [insert into u_upload (version, filename, us_id, size, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [us_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:296)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy232.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
        at com.petehallw.storage.UploadStoreManager.putUpload(UploadStoreManager.java:113)
        at com.petehallw.service.attachment.AttachmentCreator.createUpload(AttachmentCreator.java:227)
        at com.petehallw.service.attachment.AttachmentCreator.createAttachment(AttachmentCreator.java:89)
        at com.petehallw.service.attachment.AttachmentService.createAttachment(AttachmentService.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy242.createAttachment(Unknown Source)
        at com.petehallw.rest.AttachmentController.createAttachment(AttachmentController.java:311)
        at com.petehallw.rest.AttachmentController.createReferrerAttachment(AttachmentController.java:191)
        at com.petehallw.rest.AttachmentController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7fdbbe04.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:100)
        at com.petehallw.security.AuthorisationIntegrationTestFilter.blockAuthorisationTestRequest(AuthorisationIntegrationTestFilter.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.petehallw.container.rest.ContainerAttachmentController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba5042d.createReferrerAttachment(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.petehallw.rest.DisabledHttpSessionFilter.doFilter(DisabledHttpSessionFilter.java:28)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2511)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:105)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.getBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:201)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3159)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3699)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1457)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1443)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.flush(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:533)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:504)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        ... 103 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into u_upload (version, filename, us_id, size, id) values (0, 'upload.png', NULL, NULL, 1000) was aborted: ERROR: null value in column "us_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (1000, 0, upload.png, null, null).  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:148)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2179)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:479)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:835)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeBatch(PgPreparedStatement.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:345)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:345)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:345)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:119)
        ... 141 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "us_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (1000, 0, upload.png, null, null).
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2178)
        ... 148 common frames omitted
```

UploadEntity:

```
package com.petehallw.jpa;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
@Table(name = "u_upload")
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name="u_seq_gen", sequenceName="sq_u_id", allocationSize=1)
public class UploadEntity
{        
    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name="filename", nullable=false)
    private java.lang.String filename;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name="us_id", nullable=false)
    private java.lang.Long uploadStoreId;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name="size", nullable=false)
    private java.lang.Integer size;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "u_seq_gen")
    private Long id;

    @Override
    public Integer getVersion()
    {
        return this.version;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setVersion(final Integer version)
    {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public void setFilename(java.lang.String filename)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void setUploadStoreId(java.lang.Long uploadStoreId)
    {
        this.uploadStoreId = uploadStoreId;
    }

    public void setSize(java.lang.Integer size)
    {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public java.lang.String getFilename()
    {
        return this.filename;
    }

    public java.lang.Long getUploadStoreId()
    {
        return this.uploadStoreId;
    }

    public java.lang.Integer getSize()
    {
        return this.size;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you store the ID of an entity in another entity instead of using an association? Why do you save the entity before all the properties are populated? Why don't you read the stack trace of the exception to find out when the flush happens?

Comment: @JBNizet I am not sure of the reason for not using association, I could look into that. Can I remove the first `save` entirely? And will the `saveAndFlush` also flush the `uploadStoreEntity`? I read the stack trace and I get a `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException` when trying to insert into the u_upload table.

Comment: Don't ask me. Just test it, and you'll know. Why do you think you need to save the same entity twice? flush() means "save all the modifications to the database". It doesn't take any argument. So it's not related to any specific entity.

Comment: I need the first `save` in order to have an Id when calling `uploadEntity.getId()` a couple of lines below. Still not sure what the problem is.

Comment: If we were able to read the complete and exact stack trace of the exception, we would know what the problem is, and where it happens.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the stack trace to the question

Comment: If `com.petehallw.storage.UploadStoreManager.putUpload(UploadStoreManager.java:113)` indeed refers to the line calling `saveAndFlush()` in the posted code, then either the value returned by `uploadStoreEntity.getId()` is null, or there is a bug in the entity.

Comment: @JBNizet The value returned by `uploadStoreEntity.getId()` is 1. Strangely it was working before I added the `NOT NULL` constraint to *us_id*, and used `this.uploadStoreDao.saveAndFlush` instead of `this.uploadStoreDao.save`..

Comment: That doesn't help me to help you. Confirm that the line 113 is the line calling saveAndFlush() in the posted code, and post the code of your entity if you want help. If I can't see your code, I can't find a bug in that code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190205/discussion-between-petehallw-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: I don't chat...

Comment: @JBNizet OK, I said "Thanks for your help, I can confirm that is the line 113. I've added the code for my UploadEntity"